# Obter o valor da soma de inputs com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa noite pessoal.

Não consigo montar um script legal para isso.
Por exemplo, tenho quatro inputs e, logo após eu preencher alguns deles, gostaria de exibir o resultado da soma dos inputs.

Alguém tem algum exemplo funcionando que possa me auxiliar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você não postou código nem deu detalhes sobre o teu problema específico (evite isso). Porém, de acordo com a descrição é possível apresentar uma solução na qual você poderá se basear.

```js
$(".input-teste").change(function(){
  var total = 0;
  $(".input-teste").each(function(index,element){
     if ($(element).val()) {
       total+= parseInt($(element).val());
     }
 });
 $(".show-total").text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="input-teste" type="text" value="" ><br>
<input class="input-teste" type="text" value="" ><br>
<input class="input-teste" type="text" value="" ><br>
<input class="input-teste" type="text" value="" ><br>
<br>
Total: <label class="show-total"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários jeitos de conseguir isso.

Vou colaborar com um exemplo em que seja necessário trabalhar com decimais e desconsiderar valores não numéricos;

```js
$('input').css('margin-bottom', '5px').on('change', function() {
  
  var v = 0;  
  
  $('input').each(function(i,e) {   
    
    if ($(e).val()) {
      
      var i = $(e).val().replace(/\,/g,'.');
      
      if (isNaN(i)) { $(e).val(''); return; }
          
      v += parseFloat(i);
   
      $('div').text('Total: ' + v.toFixed(2));

    
    }
    
    });
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" ><br>
<input type="text" value="" ><br>
<input type="text" value="" ><br>
<input type="text" value="" ><br>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando as respostas dos outros colaboradores, segue abaixo um exemplo fazendo uso dos métodos [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) do objeto [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```js
function extrairValor(elemento) {
  return parseInt(elemento.value, 10);
}

function funcaoSoma(valorAnterior, valor) {
  return valorAnterior + valor || valorAnterior;
}

function somarValoresPorSeletor(seletor) {
  return $(seletor)
    .toArray()
    .map(extrairValor)
    .reduce(funcaoSoma);
}

function onCampoChange() {

  var resultado = somarValoresPorSeletor('input');

  $('h1').find('span').html(resultado);

}

$(function() {

  onCampoChange();

  $('input').on('change keyup', onCampoChange);

});
```

```css
input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>resultado: <span></span></h1>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="3" />
  </li>
</ul>
```